# Prove that $D+(-D)=\tilde{0}$ for every Dedekind cut $D$ ("Supplement for Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler).

Tags: solution-verification, real-numbers

I am reading "Supplement for Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.

I proved 0.24(f).
But I am not sure that my proof is ok or not.
Is my proof ok or not?
Even if my proof is ok, I wonder my proof is too long.
Please tell me a smarter proof.

> 0.21 Definition
> A *Dedekind cut* is a nonempty subset $D$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the following properties:
>
> - $D\neq\mathbb{Q}$;
> - $D$ contains all rational numbers less than any element of $D$; in other words, if $b\in D$, then $a\in D$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $a<b$;
> - $D$ does not contain a largest element.

> 0.23 Definition
>
> - Suppose $C$ and $D$ are Dedekind cuts. Then $C+D$ is defined by $$C+D=\{c+d : c\in C, d\in D\}.$$
> - The Dedekind cut $\tilde{0}$ is defined by $$\tilde{0}=\{a\in\mathbb{Q} : a<0\}.$$
> - Suppose $D$ is a Dedekind cut. Then $-D$ is defined by $$-D=\{a\in\mathbb{Q} : a<-b\text{ for some }b\in\mathbb{Q}\text{ with } b\notin D\}.$$

> 0.24
> (f) $D+(-D)=\tilde{0}$ for every Dedekind cut $D$.

---

> Lemma 1:
> Let $D$ be a Dedekind cut and $D\neq\tilde{0}$.
> Then, $0\in D$ or $0\in -D$ holds.
>
> Proof:
> Assume that $0\notin D$.
> Let $x\in D$.
> Then, $x\neq 0$ since $0\notin D$ and $x\in D$.
> If $x>0$, then $0\in D$ since $D$ is a Dedekind cut.
> We assumed $0\notin D$.
> So, this is a contradiction.
> So, $x<0$.
> So, $D\subset\tilde{0}$.
> We assumed $D\neq\tilde{0}$.
> So, $D\subsetneq\tilde{0}$.
> So, there exists $b\in\tilde{0}-D$.
> Then, $b<0$ and $b\notin D$.
> Then, $0<-b$ and $b\notin D$.
> So, $0\in -D$.

> Lemma 2:
> Let $D$ be a Dedekind cut and $D\neq\tilde{0}$.
> $0\in D$ and $0\notin -D$ holds or $0\in -D$ and $0\notin D$ holds.
>
> Proof:
> By Lemma 1, $0\in -D$ or $0\in D$ holds.
>
> Let $0\in -D$.
> There exists $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $b\notin D$ and $0<-b$.
> Then, $b<0$ and $b\notin D$.
> So, $0\notin D$.
>
> Let $0\in D$.
> We proved if $0\in -D$, then $0\notin D$.
> So, if $0\in D$, then $0\notin -D$.
> So, $0\notin -D$.

> $D+(-D)=\tilde{0}$ for every Dedekind cut $D$.
> Proof:
> We prove $D+(-D)\subset\tilde{0}$.
> Let $x\in D+(-D)$.
> We can write $x=d+a$, where $d\in D$ and $a\in -D$.
> Then, there exists $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a<-b$ and $b\notin D$.
> So, $d+a<d-b$.
> Since $d\in D$ and $b\notin D$, $d<b$.
> So, $d+a<d-b<0$.
> So, $x=d+a\in\tilde{0}$.
>
> Next we prove that $\tilde{0}+(-\tilde{0})=\tilde{0}$.
> Since $\tilde{0}$ is a Dedekind cut, $\tilde{0}+(-\tilde{0})\subset\tilde{0}$ by the above argument.
> Let $x\in\tilde{0}$.
> Then, $x<0$.
> Since $\frac{x}{2}<0$, $\frac{x}{2}\in\tilde{0}$.
> Since $\frac{x}{2}<-0$ and $0\notin\tilde{0}$, $\frac{x}{2}\in -\tilde{0}$.
> So, $x=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2}\in\tilde{0}+(-\tilde{0})$.
> So, $\tilde{0}\subset\tilde{0}+(-\tilde{0})$.
>
> Next we prove $\tilde{0}\subset D+(-D)$ for $D\neq\tilde{0}$.
> Let $c\in\tilde{0}$.
> Then, $c<0$.
>
> By Lemma 2, $0\in D$ and $0\notin -D$ holds or $0\in -D$ and $0\notin D$ holds.
>
> (i) We consider the case $0\in D$ and $0\notin -D$:
> Assume that $c\in -D$.
> Then, $c=0+c\in D+(-D)$.
> Assume that $c\notin -D$.
> Since $-D\neq\emptyset$, there exists $x\in -D$.
> There exists $n\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}$ such that $nc<x$.
> If $nc<x$ for some $n\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}$, then $nc\in -D$.
> So, $\{n\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}\mid nc\in -D\}\neq\emptyset$.
> Let $n_0:=\min\{n\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}\mid nc\in -D\}$.
> Since $-D$ does not contain a largest element, there exists $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\varepsilon>0$ and $n_0c+\varepsilon\in -D$.
> If $-(n_0-1)c-\varepsilon\notin D$, then $(n_0-1)c\in -D$ since $(n_0-1)c<-(-(n_0-1)c-\varepsilon)$.
> This is a contradiction.
> So, $-(n_0-1)c-\varepsilon\in D$.
> Then, $c=(-(n_0-1)c-\varepsilon)+(n_0c+\varepsilon)\in D+(-D)$.
>
> (ii) We consider the case $0\in -D$ and $0\notin D$:
> Assume that $c\in D$.
> Then, $c=c+0\in D+(-D)$.
> Assume that $c\notin D$.
> Since $D\neq\emptyset$, there exists $x\in D$.
> There exists $n\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}$ such that $nc<x$.
> If $nc<x$ for some $n\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}$, then $nc\in D$.
> So, $\{n\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}\mid nc\in D\}\neq\emptyset$.
> Let $n_0:=\min\{n\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}\mid nc\in D\}$.
> Since $D$ does not contain a largest element, there exists $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\varepsilon>0$ and $n_0c+\varepsilon\in D$.
> $-(n_0-1)c-\varepsilon<-(n_0-1)c$ and $(n_0-1)c\notin D$, so $-(n_0-1)c-\varepsilon\in -D$.
> Then, $c=(n_0c+\varepsilon)+(-(n_0-1)c-\varepsilon)\in D+(-D)$.

Comment: In your proof of lemma 1 you ruled out $x>0$ and then went on with treating $x<0$ as if that followed from its not being the case that $x>0.$ However all one knows at that point is that $x \le 0.$

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you very much for your comment. I modified my proof of Lemma 1.